# How to map hardware interrupt to virq without dts under arm?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, interrupt, arm64

In certain cases, a virtual device may lack a device tree node. However, there is a possibility that user want to assign a software triggable Shared Processor Interrupt (SPI) to it. How to do it?

Comment: I just don't understand why downvote without any word

Answer (score -1):

User can fill fwspec in code, take SPI 34 for example:

```c
+        gic_node = of_find_compatible_node(NULL, NULL, "arm,gic-400");
+        if (!gic_node) {
+                pr_err("failed to find GIC node!\n");
+                return -ENODEV;
+        }
+
+        fwspec.fwnode = of_node_to_fwnode(gic_node);
+        fwspec.param_count = 3;
+        fwspec.param[0] = GIC_SPI;
+        fwspec.param[1] = 34;
+        fwspec.param[2] = 4;
+        virq = irq_create_fwspec_mapping(&fwspec);
+        if (!virq)
+                pr_err("%s: failed to map software irq\n", __func__);
+        else
+                pr_info("%s: map software irq correctly! virq is %d\n",
+                        __func__, virq);
+
+        ret = request_irq(virq, your_handler, IRQF_ONESHOT,
+                          "softirq-0", dev);
+        if (ret) {
+                dev_err(dev, "Error %d register irq 0x%x\n", ret,
+                        virq);
+                return -EINVAL;
+        }
```